# Is there a technical reason why you can't have multiple cascade paths in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to implement a table in TSQL that references another table twice in 2 different columns, and applying cascade UPDATE/DELETE to those references:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Discussion](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(100000,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [originated_user_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Discussion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_Badge_Count](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [discussion_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [chat_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [count] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User_Badge_Count] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User_Badge_Count] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_User_Badge_Count_count]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [count]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User_Badge_Count]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Badge_Count_Chat] FOREIGN KEY([chat_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Discussion] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User_Badge_Count] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Badge_Count_Chat]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User_Badge_Count]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Badge_Count_Discussion] FOREIGN KEY([discussion_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Discussion] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User_Badge_Count] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Badge_Count_Discussion]
GO
```

It's done this way because we can consider a discussion to be a "discussion" or a "chat", and we want to reference as such in the badge table.  However, trying to create these 2 cascades to the same table results in the TSQL error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_User_Badge_Count_Discussion' on table 'User_Badge_Count' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Is there a technical reason for this restriction?  It seems a bit arbitrary; the DBMS could just update/delete the row if *either* foreign key referenced is updated/deleted?

Comment: AFAIK, its' mainly to do with locking/deadlocking problems, as well as possible logic errors involving Halloween Protection. I don't think any answer could possibly give a technical reason why, it probably just comes down to: some cases *are* possible, but the compiler is arbitrarily over-cautious and no-one has bothered to try fix it.